# How to Execute Script As Root When User Logs Out?

Tags: scripts, root, logout

I need to run a script/command as root each time a user logs out (Just need to kill a root process). Is there a way? I'm running KDE5/Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Each version of Ubuntu uses some variation of `lightdm` desktop manager ( also known simply as login screen ). There is an option known as `session-cleanup-script` , which runs as root upon user logging out. This is to be placed into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file in the following format:

```
[SeatDefaults]
session-cleanup-script=/path/to/script.sh
```

**NOTE**:

> Later versions of lightdm (15.10 onwards) have replaced the obsolete [SeatDefaults] with [Seat:*] ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM))

For other options, see `zless /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz` in terminal.